# VimPlug, Vim won't load plugins: E117: Unknown function : plug#begin;

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-plug, autoload

On Macbook Pro, Terminal, standard Vim, VimPlug

When I start vim I get the following message:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/me/.vimrc:
line 159:
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
```

In my .vimrc I have the following:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
[a bunch of plugins]
call plug#end()
```

As far as I can tell the setup is correct but vim doesn't recognize the function so it can't load any of my plugins. Everything was working before. I figured this has something to do with the plug.vim in ~/.vim/autoload. However when I try to access the autoload directory I get this error:

```
cd: permission denied: autoload
```

This might explain why vim isn't able to call the plug#begin function, but I don't know how to fix it.

**UPDATE:** Output of `ls -l ~/.vim`:

```
total 0
drwxr-x---    5 root  wheel    160 Feb 27 10:27 autoload
drwxr-xr-x    8 gabe  staff    256 Nov 27 14:40 colors
drwxr-xr-x   30 gabe  staff    960 Feb 27 10:19 plugged
drwxr-xr-x  370 gabe  staff  11840 Feb 27 17:13 view
```

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.vim/` look like?

Comment: I'm guessing `chmod +x ~/.vim/autoload` might resolve at least part of the problem...

Comment: @filbranden total 0
`total 0`
`drwxr-x---    5 root  wheel    160 Feb 27 10:27 autoload`
`drwxr-xr-x    8 gabe  staff    256 Nov 27 14:40 colors`
`drwxr-xr-x   30 gabe  staff    960 Feb 27 10:19 plugged`
`drwxr-xr-x  370 gabe  staff  11840 Feb 27 17:13 view`

Comment: @filbranden when i try chmod i get this:

`chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Users/gabe/.vim/autoload: Operation not permitted`

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I try to reload the file with the :source % it gives me the same error then try to save and exit file and try to reload the file with source command again it gives the same error but when I try to open vim editor through vim command and try to run :PlugIntall its work for me.

Comment: @laxmibarpete Does the existing answer on this question solve the problem for you? If not, I would recommend that you post a new **question** here with the particulars of your problem. Feel free to reference this question and also list the output of commands that were used to troubleshoot the issue here (so we can confirm it's not the same reason.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you created the `autoload` directory (or ran the `wget` command to install vim-plug) under `sudo`.

Running it under `sudo` will be bad because it will create files and directories that only root will be able to access!

To fix that now:

```
$ sudo chown -Rh gabe:staff ~/.vim
$ chmod -R a+rX,u+w,go-w ~/.vim
```

This should reset the ownership of all the files and directories under `.vim` to your user.

It will also reset the file permissions to their default. Not strictly necessary, but cleaner that way.

Comment: the second line doesn't work, `chmod: Invalid file mode: a=rX,` but the first one did and it looks like i can access the file again

Comment: @Gabe Hmmm, MacOS. Does this work? `a+rX,u+w,go-w` for the middle argument with the mode...

Comment: Seems like it worked! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gabe If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. See the help topic on [what to do with answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked;)